# I am trying to create a function that calculates z-score that loops through a dataframe

Tags: python, function, loops, dataframe, statistics

I know I could use the z-score function with a stats plugin but I am trying to practice creating functions but am stuck on this:
Create a function that takes a DataFrame, and a list of columns to be standardized (z-scores), as inputs and return a DataFrame as output. Inside this function, loop through the DataFrame columns supplied as input and standard the values of these columns. The columns must contain only numerical values. Inside your function, you may need to initialize an empty DataFrame and populate it with columns having standardized values. The returned DataFrame should contain only the columns supplied as input. Each column of the returned DataFrame should contain standardized values only.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it wont allow me to reply in code format but i am mostly having trouble getting it to go through the coloumn '''def z_score(f):
    
    empty=[]
    for i in f:
        mean=np.mean(i)
        std= np.std(i)
        z=(i-mean)/std
        empty.append(z)
        
z_score(cereals_data3['Carbo'])